# d3 - Where to catch missing node loopin error?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm using d3 for my app and I want to know where can I set the try/catch method in my app. 
sometimes I set links without matching nodes, I know that its a bug but I want to catch this error.

at the moment I get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'sadd-123-c3c-sdc ....
```

And it's looping a lot of time (800+). 
Where can I set a try/catch to handle this kind of situation?

So far I've tried here

```
try {
    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
}
catch(err){
  console.log('print the error', error)
}
```

Also in here

```
  this.simulation
  .nodes(<any>this.data.nodes)
  .on('tick', () => { this.setNodePostion(); });

setNodePostion() {
try {

  this.node
    .attr('cx', (d) => {
      return d.x;
    }).attr('cy', (d) => {
      return dd.y;
    })
    .attr('transform', (d) => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')');

  this.link
    .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
    .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
    .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
    .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('third', error);
}



}
```

Any idea where can I place this try/catch? 
THX

I'm using d3 version 5 and Angular

Answer (score 0):

I found where Should I place the try-catch but the solution was the catch action.

Place the try/catch before the simulation actions and in the catch stop the simulation

```
try{
    this.simulation
      .nodes(<any>this.data.nodes)
      .on('tick', () => { this.setNodePostion(); });

this.simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(this.width / 2, this.height / 2));
        .force<any>('link')
        .links(this.data.links);

   } catch (err){
    this.simulation.stop();
}
```